# How to merge multiple images into single image like matrix?

Tags: android

I am working on one application for it I have multiple images and I want to create one image from it. I use the below code for it but the output of the single image is only vertical format.

```
String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/MERGE/";
    BitmapFactory.Options options;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> myBitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    int vWidth = 0;
    int vHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        try {
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath + "img" + i + ".jpg",
                    options);
            vWidth = bitmap.getWidth() > vWidth ? bitmap.getWidth()
                    : vWidth;
            vHeight += bitmap.getHeight();
            myBitmapList.add(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            options = null;
            bitmap = null;
            System.gc();
            Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
            Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        }
    }

    Bitmap vTargetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vWidth, vHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas vCanvas = new Canvas(vTargetBitmap);
    int vInsertY = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++) {
        vCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmapList.get(i), (float) 0f,
                (float) vInsertY, null);
        vInsertY += myBitmapList.get(i).getHeight();
    }

    String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/" + tmpImg);
        vTargetBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The actual output I want is something like below image.

[Actual output I want is something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB6Pu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
 private Bitmap mergeMultiple(ArrayList<Bitmap> parts) {

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(parts.get(0).getWidth() * 2, parts.get(0).getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(parts.get(i), parts.get(i).getWidth() * (i % 2), parts.get(i).getHeight() * (i / 2), paint);
        }
        return result;
    }
```